# A ggplot2 equivalent of the lines() function in basic plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

For reasons I won't go into I need to plot a vertical normal curve on a blank ggplot2 graph. The following code gets it done as a series of points with x,y coordinates

```
dfBlank <- data.frame()

g <- ggplot(dfBlank) + xlim(0.58,1) + ylim(-0.2,113.2)

hdiLo <- 31.88
hdiHi <- 73.43
yComb <- seq(hdiLo, hdiHi, length  = 75)
xVals <- 0.79 - (0.06*dnorm(yComb, 52.65, 10.67))/0.05
dfVertCurve <- data.frame(x = xVals, y = yComb)

g + geom_point(data = dfVertCurve, aes(x = x, y = y), size = 0.01)
```

The curve is clearly discernible but is a series of points. The `lines()` function in basic plot would turn these points into a smooth line.

Is there a ggplot2 equivalent?

Comment: `+stat_smooth` , `?stat_smooth`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two different ways to do it.

#### geom_segment

The first uses `geom_segment` to 'link' each point with its next one.

```
hdiLo <- 31.88
hdiHi <- 73.43
yComb <- seq(hdiLo, hdiHi, length  = 75)
xVals <- 0.79 - (0.06*dnorm(yComb, 52.65, 10.67))/0.05
dfVertCurve <- data.frame(x = xVals, y = yComb)


library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
    xlim(0.58, 1) + 
    ylim(-0.2, 113.2) +
    geom_segment(data = dfVertCurve, aes(x = x, xend = dplyr::lead(x), y = y, yend = dplyr::lead(y)), size = 0.01)
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

As you can see it just link the points you created. The last point does not have a next one, so the last segment is removed (See the `warning`)

#### stat_function

The second one, which I think is better and more `ggplot`ish, utilize `stat_function()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
f = function(x) .79 - (.06 * dnorm(x, 52.65, 10.67)) / .05

hdiLo <- 31.88
hdiHi <- 73.43
yComb <- seq(hdiLo, hdiHi, length  = 75)

ggplot() + 
    xlim(-0.2, 113.2) + 
    ylim(0.58, 1) + 
    stat_function(data = data.frame(yComb), fun = f) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

This build a proper function (`y = f(x)`), plot it. Note that it is build on the X axis and then flipped. Because of this the `xlim` and `ylim` are inverted.

Comment: Thank you @GGamba. These are both great solutions but are not quite do what I need. The dframe in my original `ggplot()` is not actually blank as in my example, it is a scatter plot with regression lines superimposed. So I cannot flip it. I need a *self-contained* way of drawing a line/curve between many x,y coordinates, with the `data =` call in the `geom_` being the `dfVertCurve` dframe. The `lines` function in basic plot can do this, but I know of no function in ggplot.

Comment: Kind of hard to understand your real need w/o a real example. I still do not understand what you need.

Comment: I need to be able to superimpose a curve over a blank ggplot graph based on an empty dataframe. Your solutions all require using the x,y coordinates contained in the `dVertCurve` dataframe as the `data =` argument in the original `ggplot()` and then mapping to that. I need a way to join the dots that does not require mapping to the oriiginal `ggplot()`.

Comment: Both `geom_segment` and `stat_function` (and every `geom_` and `stat_*` really) accept  a `data` argument. Updating the answer to make it explicit

Comment: I sincerely thank you for taking the time @GGamba. At first I was getting a blank plot but then when I changed the size of the line to `size = 0.5` suddenly I could see it. Thank you for your help. I don't suppose you'd care to explain what the `dplyr::lead(x)` function does?